# Selecionar elementos da DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Estou tentando selecionar um elemento da DOM via js para executar uma ação ao clicar. Porém o programa não responde ao click. Como devo proceder?

segue o código!

```
const modalOverlay = document.querySelector('.modal_overlay')
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

for (let card of cards) {
  card.addEventListener("click", function(){
    modalOverlay.classList.add('active')
  })
}

document.querySelector(".close_modal").addEventListener('click', function() {
  modalOverlay.classList.remove('active')
})
```

Comment: cara pq vc não usa forEach() em vez de for (let card of cards)

Comment: complementando o que o colega falou:

const modalOverlay = document.querySelector('.modal_overlay');
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

cards.forEach(function(card){
    card.addEventListener("click", function(){
        modalOverlay.classList.add('active');
    })
});

let teste = document.querySelector(".form-input");
teste.addEventListener('click', function(){
    modalOverlay.classList.remove('active')
});

Comment: Obrigado galera , consegui resolver aqui.
Muito Obrigado pela ajuda!